# triple NIntegrate fails

Tags: numerical-integration

Here's m problem simpler in terms of codes

```
Clear["Global`*"]
e = 0.454648; A = 1.6297; rs = 3.68888; kb = 0.001872041; Na = 
 6.02214129*10^23;
ep = 0.2961; p = 3.78;
pot[r_] := -e (1 - (1 - Exp[-A (r - rs)])^2)

B[T_] := -2 \[Pi] Na NIntegrate[(Exp[-pot[r]/(kb T)] - 1) r^2, {r, 0, 
    Infinity}] 10^-24
C2[T_] := 8 \[Pi]^2 /3 Na ^2 10^-48 NIntegrate[
   NIntegrate[
    NIntegrate[
     r12^2 (1 - Exp[-pot[r12]/(kb T)]) r13^2 (1 - 
        Exp[-pot[r13]/(kb T)]) (1 - 
        Exp[-pot[Sqrt[r12^2 + r13^2 - 2 r12 r13 n]]/(kb T)]), {r13, 0,
       150}], {r12, 0, 150}], {n, 1, 150}]
```

My problem is that second integration function C2[T_] keeps giving me zero with 3 warnings of

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option. >>

and if I use one NIntegrate function

```
C2[T_] := 
 8 \[Pi]^2 /3 Na ^2 NIntegrate[
   r12^2 (1 - Exp[-pot[r12]/(kb T)]) r13^2 (1 - 
      Exp[-pot[r13]/(kb T)]) (1 - 
      Exp[-pot[Sqrt[r12^2 + r13^2 - 2 r12 r13 n]]/(kb T)]), {r13, 0, 
    150}, {r12, 0, 150}, {n, 1, 150}]
```

I get 3 of this warning

> NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision in the global
>   error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent
>   integral. >>

any ideas how to fix it?

The original integration is

[image]

Comment: Some suggestions:  1) please don't use capital C because it is already used in Mathematica.  Maybe try small c.  2)  T is not defined in your equation, neither as a parameter nor as a variable for integration.

Comment: sorry I had aleady noticed the capital c error but I have defned T all exponentials are divided by (kb T).

Comment: Another issue: 1) I would combine all the NIntegrates into one  2) Is it possible for the argument to the Sqrt to become negative?  `Plot3D[r12^2 + r13^2 - 2 r12 r13 n /. n -> 10, {r13, 0, 150}, {r12, 0,
   150}]`

Comment: Another suggestion: if you need the 10^-48 stuff for scaling, then you may want to move that inside of the NIntegrate so that it does not blow up or even vanish.

Comment: You are probably calculating a partition function there, the integral is dominated (for low T) by the minimum value of the exponent integrand (ground state energy), therefore it is better to first find the minimum value (and location if you can) to factor out the exponent of the minimum and concentrate the integral only around the location of the minimum (see Laplace and Stationary Phase approximation).

Comment: Im trying to calculate third virial coefficient from potential energies I calculated from molecular modelling,  ill try to take a look into phase approximation so you think the problem is that the integral is hard to be calculated?

Comment: Since `T` is undefined (i.e. not given a real value), I'll take it be a warmish temp., say T = 300 K.  Then `(1 - Exp[-pot[Sqrt[r12^2 + r13^2 - 2 r12 r13 n]]/(kb 300)]) /. {r12 -> 2, r13 -> 2, n -> 10}` produces a pretty big number with pretty big imaginary part.  Is the radicand supposed to become negative over part of the region of integration?  Also in V9.0.1, instead of your error message, I get `Message[NIntegrate::errprec]`, "Catastrophic loss of precision...".  Are you certain that the function is copied correctly above?

Comment: I'm using the same version, anyways I updated the question with information you asked for.

Comment: Have you tried other forms for this integration?
try
[link](http://books.google.fi/books?id=VSwc1XUmYpcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=molecular+thermodynamics&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YcbSUfShGIOqtAbezYCoCA&redir_esc=y)

Comment: I think `kB` represents Boltzmann constant? If so, why it's `0.001872041`?